# Reading a string separately from columns in a csv file

Tags: python, string, csv, file, google-colaboratory

I have a `.csv` file with 10 columns. In the 3rd column, I have the string *Argentina,Chile,USA* . I want to get each country separately. How can I do that in python colab?

Comment: Provide a sample of the data file.  If it is a "proper" CSV file with comma-delimited columns and quotes around columns *containing* commas, the `csv`' module or `pandas` should be used to parse it.

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        columnsData = line.split(",")
        countries = columnsData[2].split(",")
```

The `countries` variables is a list with all countries names starting from 0 index.

Comment: I want from the specific column(id) to find all the strings Argentina,Chile,USA. In the file i have a lot of times the same id.

Comment: In the code `columnsData[2]`, here "2" denotes the column ID. As you said, you want from 3rd column, so I put like this. You can change this to whatever column ID you need.

Comment: This wouldn't work if a single column contains commas.  There wouldn't be any commas left to split in the `countries` line.  The OP indicates the 3rd column *has* commas.  Need a sample of the actual file, and should use the `csv` module or `pandas`.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I didn't think of that scenario @MarkTolonen. In that case, we would need a sample of the CSV file and check what is the column delimiter.